# getting x,y from a scatter plot with multiple datasets?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a scatter plot that is composed of different calls for *scatter*:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def onpick3(event):
    index = event.ind
    print '--------------'
    print index
    artist = event.artist
    print artist

fig_handle = plt.figure()

x,y = np.random.rand(10),np.random.rand(10)
x1,y1 = np.random.rand(10),np.random.rand(10)

axes_size = 0.1,0.1,0.9,0.9
ax = fig_handle.add_axes(axes_size)

p = ax.scatter (x,y, marker='*', s=60, color='r', picker=True, lw=2)
p1 = ax.scatter (x1,y1, marker='*', s=60, color='b', picker=True, lw=2)

fig_handle.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick3)
plt.show()
```

I'd like the points to be clickable, and get the x,y of the selected indexes.
However since `scatter` is being called more than once, I get the same indexes twice, so I cant use `x[index]` inside the `onpick3` method

Is there a straightforward way to get the points?

It seems that `event.artist` gives back the same `PathCollection` that is given back from `scatter` (`p` and `p1` in this case).
But I couldn't find any way to use it to extract the `x,y` of the selected indexes
Tried using `event.artist.get_paths()` - but it doesn't seem to be giving back all the scatter points, but only the one that I clicked on..so I'm really not sure what `event.artist` is giving back and what are the `event.artist.get_paths()` function is giving back

## EDIT

it seems that `event.artist._offsets` gives an array with the relevant offsets, but for some reason when trying to use `event.artist.offsets`I get

```
AttributeError: 'PathCollection' object has no attribute 'offsets'
```

(although if I understand the [docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/collections_api.html?highlight=pathcollection#matplotlib.collections.PathCollection), it should be there)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the x, y coordinates for the collection that `scatter` returns, use `event.artist.get_offsets()` (Matplotlib has explicit getters and setters for mostly historical reasons. All `get_offsets` does is return `self._offsets`, but the public interface is through the "getter".).

So, to complete your example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def onpick3(event):
    index = event.ind
    xy = event.artist.get_offsets()
    print '--------------'
    print xy[index]


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x, y = np.random.random((2, 10))
x1, y1 = np.random.random((2, 10))

p = ax.scatter(x, y, marker='*', s=60, color='r', picker=True)
p1 = ax.scatter(x1, y1, marker='*', s=60, color='b', picker=True)

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick3)
plt.show()
```

However, if you're not varying things by a 3rd or 4th variable, you may not want to use `scatter` to plot points.  Use `plot` instead. `scatter` returns a collection that's much more difficult to work with than the `Line2D` that `plot` returns.  (If you do go the route of using `plot`, you'd use `x, y = artist.get_data()`.)

Finally, not to plug my own project too much, but if you might find [`mpldatacursor`](https://github.com/joferkington/mpldatacursor) useful. It abstracts away a lot of you're doing here.

If you decide to go that route, your code would look similar to:

Comment: thanks! I don't know how I missed that in the documentation.Actually `mpldatacursor` seems very nice, but I couldn't find how to two things: 1. when I have two adjacent points and I click I see only one [I'd like to know how many points are there]. 2. sometimes I'd like to save the figure, but I couldn't find how to remove the annotation after clicking on it.

Comment: @nopede11 - Sorry I didn't reply before now! 1) To display the number of points, use something like `datacursor(formatter=lambda **kwargs: len(kwargs['ind']))` (that won't display the x,y position, but it's easy to modify the formatter function to display x,y as well).  2) With the latest version, just hit the "d" key on the keyboard to hide the annotation boxes. Thanks!

Comment: For 3-dimensional scatter plots, is there a way to get the z data as well?